# Trouble updating the dots and axis of the scatter plot - d3

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, data-visualization

I have trouble updating the dots and axis of the scatter plot, and corresponding bar chart in the d3 visualization when I select a different attribute for the x-axis or y-axis. As shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEgQ3.png).

I reused the code from this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/curran/f4041cac02f19ee460dfe8b709dc24e7), made some changes to add a drop-down menu for both axis. When changing the axis from the drop-down it adds correct data points but won't remove the previous ones. I need help updating and removing the previous elements if the x-axis or y-axis are changed from the drop-down menu.

```
<!--
  An example of linked views using model.js.

  Curran Kelleher August 2014
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- A functional reactive model library. github.com/curran/model -->
    <script src="https://curran.github.io/model/cdn/model-v0.2.4.js"></script>
    <style>

      /* CSS for the visualization.
       * Curran Kelleher 4/17/2014 */

      /* Size the visualization container. */
      #container {
        position: fixed;
        top: 30px;
        bottom: 30px;
        left: 30px;
        right: 30px;
      }

      /* Style the visualization.
       * This CSS is copied verbatim from the
       * D3 scatter plot example found at
       * http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887118 */

      body {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
      }

      .axis path,
      .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
      }

      .dot {
        fill: black;
      }

      /* The following CSS is for brushing,
       * adapted from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4343214 */

      .dot.selected {
        fill: red;
      }

      .brush .extent {
        stroke: gray;
        fill-opacity: .125;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div id = "axisSelectors">
      <b>x-axis:</b>
        <select id="xSelector" onchange="onCategoryChanged()">
        <option value="sepalWidth">sepalWidth</option>
        <option value="petalWidth">petalWidth</option>
        </select>

      <b>y-axis:</b>
        <select id="ySelector" onchange="onCategoryChanged()">
        <option value="sepalLength">sepalLength</option>
        <option value="petalLength">petalLength</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <script>

function onCategoryChanged() {
    var select = d3.select('#xSelector').node();
    // Get current value of select element
    var x_category = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    // Update chart with the selected category of letters
    var select = d3.select('#ySelector').node();
    var y_category = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    main(x_category,y_category);
}

function BarChart (container) {
  var defaults = {
        margin: {
          top: 20,
          right: 20,
          bottom: 30,
          left: 40
        },
        yAxisNumTicks: 10,
        yAxisTickFormat: ""
      },
      model = Model(defaults),
      xAxis = d3.svg.axis().orient("bottom"),
      yAxis = d3.svg.axis().orient("left")
      svg = d3.select(container).append('svg')

        // Use absolute positioning on the SVG element
        // so that CSS can be used to position the div later
        // according to the model `box.x` and `box.y` properties.
        .style('position', 'absolute'),

      g = svg.append("g"),
      xAxisG = g.append("g").attr("class", "x axis"),
      yAxisG = g.append("g").attr("class", "y axis"),
      yAxisText = yAxisG.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end");

  // Encapsulate D3 Conventional Margins.
  // See also http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3019563
  model.when(["box", "margin"], function (box, margin) {
    model.width = box.width - margin.left - margin.right,
    model.height = box.height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  });
  model.when("margin", function (margin) {
    g.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  });

  // Adjust Y axis tick mark parameters.
  // See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_tickFormat
  model.when(['yAxisNumTicks', 'yAxisTickFormat'], function (count, format) {
    yAxis.ticks(count, format);
  });

  // Respond to changes in size and offset.
  model.when("box", function (box) {

    // Resize the svg element that contains the visualization.
    svg.attr("width", box.width).attr("height", box.height);

    // Set the CSS `left` and `top` properties
    // to move the SVG element to `(box.x, box.y)`
    // relative to the container div to apply the offset.
    svg
      .style('left', box.x + 'px')
      .style('top', box.y + 'px');
  });

  model.when("height", function (height) {
    xAxisG.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");
  });

  model.when(["data", "xAttribute", "width"], function (data, xAttribute, width) {
    model.xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1)
      .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d[xAttribute]; }));
  });

  model.when(["data", "yAttribute", "height"], function (data, yAttribute, height) {
    model.yScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0])
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[yAttribute]; })]);
  });

  model.when(["xScale"], function (xScale) {
    xAxis.scale(xScale)
    xAxisG.call(xAxis);
  });

  model.when(["yScale"], function (yScale) {
    yAxis.scale(yScale)
    yAxisG.call(yAxis);
  });

  model.when("yAxisLabel", yAxisText.text, yAxisText);

  model.when(["data", "xAttribute", "yAttribute", "xScale", "yScale", "height"],
      function (data, xAttribute, yAttribute, xScale, yScale, height) {
    var bars = g.selectAll(".bar").data(data);

    bars.enter().append("rect").attr("class", "bar");

    bars
      .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d[xAttribute]); })
      .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d[yAttribute]); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - yScale(d[yAttribute]); });

    bars.exit().remove();
  });

  return model;
}


// An adaptation of the [D3 scatter plot example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887118)
// that uses `model.js`. This version, unlike the original example,
// is model driven and reactive. When a part of the model updates,
// only the parts of the visualization that depend on those parts
// of the model are updated. There are no redundant calls to visualization
// update code when multiple properties are changed simultaneously.
//
// Draws from this brushing example for interaction:
// http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4343214
//
// See also docs on quadtree:
// https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quadtree-Geom
//
// Define the AMD module using the `define()` function
// provided by Require.js.
//define(['d3', 'model'], function (d3, Model) {
function ScatterPlot (div){
  var x = d3.scale.linear(),
      y = d3.scale.linear(),
      xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom'),
      yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient('left'),

      // Use absolute positioning so that CSS can be used
      // to position the div according to the model.
      svg = d3.select(div).append('svg').style('position', 'absolute'),
      g = svg.append('g'),
      xAxisG = g.append('g').attr('class', 'x axis'),
      yAxisG = g.append('g').attr('class', 'y axis'),
      xAxisLabel = xAxisG.append('text')
        .attr('class', 'label')
        .attr('y', -6)
        .style('text-anchor', 'end'),
      yAxisLabel = yAxisG.append('text')
        .attr('class', 'label')
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
        .attr('y', 6)
        .attr('dy', '.71em')
        .style('text-anchor', 'end'),

      // Add the dots group before the brush group,
      // so that mouse events go to the brush
      // rather than to the dots, even when the mouse is
      // on top of a dot.
      dotsG = g.append('g'),
      brushG = g.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'brush'),
      brush = d3.svg.brush()
        .on('brush', brushed),
      dots,
      quadtree,
      model = Model();

  model.when('xLabel', xAxisLabel.text, xAxisLabel);
  model.when('yLabel', yAxisLabel.text, yAxisLabel);


  model.when('margin', function (margin) {
    g.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');
  });

  model.when('box', function (box) {
    svg.attr('width', box.width)
       .attr('height', box.height);

    // Set the CSS `left` and `top` properties
    // to move the SVG element to `(box.x, box.y)`
    // relative to the container div.
    svg
      .style('left', box.x + 'px')
      .style('top', box.y + 'px')
  });

  model.when(['box', 'margin'], function (box, margin) {
    model.width = box.width - margin.left - margin.right;
    model.height = box.height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  });

  model.when('width', function (width) {
    xAxisLabel.attr('x', width);
  });

  model.when('height', function (height) {
    xAxisG.attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')');
  });

  model.when(['width', 'height'], function (width, height) {
    brush.x(d3.scale.identity().domain([0, width]));
    brush.y(d3.scale.identity().domain([0, height]));
    brushG
      .call(brush)
      .call(brush.event);
  });


  model.when(['width', 'height', 'data', 'xField', 'yField'], function (width, height, data, xField, yField) {

    // Updated the scales
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[xField]; })).nice();
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[yField]; })).nice();

    x.range([0, width]);
    y.range([height, 0]);

    // update the quadtree
    quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree()
      .x(function(d) { return x(d[xField]); })
      .y(function(d) { return y(d[yField]); })
      (data);

    // update the axes
    xAxisG.call(xAxis);
    yAxisG.call(yAxis);

    // Plot the data as dots
    dots = dotsG.selectAll('.dot').data(data);
    dots.enter().append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'dot')
      .attr('r', 3.5);
    dots
      .attr('cx', function(d) { return x(d[xField]); })
      .attr('cy', function(d) { return y(d[yField]); });
    dots.exit().remove();
  });
  return model;

  function brushed() {
    var e = brush.extent(), selectedData;
    if(dots) {
      dots.each(function(d) { d.selected = false; });
      selectedData = search(e[0][0], e[0][1], e[1][0], e[1][1]);
      dots.classed('selected', function(d) { return d.selected; });
    }
    model.selectedData = brush.empty() ? model.data : selectedData;
  }

  // Find the nodes within the specified rectangle.
  function search(x0, y0, x3, y3) {
    var selectedData = [];
    quadtree.visit(function(node, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
      var d = node.point, x, y;
      if (d) {
        x = node.x;
        y = node.y;
        d.visited = true;
        if(x >= x0 && x < x3 && y >= y0 && y < y3){
          d.selected = true;
          selectedData.push(d);
        }
      }
      return x1 >= x3 || y1 >= y3 || x2 < x0 || y2 < y0;
    });
    return selectedData;
  }
}

// The main program that assembles the linked views.
//
// Curran Kelleher 4/17/2014
//require(['d3', 'scatterPlot', 'barChart'], function (d3, ScatterPlot, BarChart) {
function main(xvar,yvar){

  // Grab the container div from the DOM.
  var div = document.getElementById('container'),

      // Add both visualizations to the same div.
      // Each will create its own SVG element.
      scatterPlot = ScatterPlot(div),
      barChart = BarChart(div);

  // Configure the scatter plot to use the iris data.
  scatterPlot.set({
    xField: xvar,
    yField: yvar,
    xLabel: xvar,
    yLabel: yvar,
    margin: { 'top': 20, 'right': 20, 'bottom': 30, 'left': 40 }
  });

  // Configure the bar chart to use the aggregated iris data.
   barChart.set({
    xAttribute: 'species',
    yAttribute: 'count',
    yAxisLabel: 'number of irises',
    margin: { 'top': 20, 'right': 20, 'bottom': 30, 'left': 40 }
  });

  // Compute the aggregated iris data in response to brushing
  // in the scatter plot, and pass it into the bar chart.
  scatterPlot.when('selectedData', function (scatterData) {
    var speciesCounts = {};

    // Aggregate scatter plot data by counting
    // the number of irises for each species.
    scatterData.forEach(function (d) {
      if(!speciesCounts[d.species]){
        speciesCounts[d.species] = 0;
      }
      speciesCounts[d.species]++;
    });

    // Flatten the object containing species counts into an array.
    // Update the bar chart with the aggregated data.
    barChart.data = Object.keys(speciesCounts).map(function (species) {
      return {
        species: species,
        count: speciesCounts[species]
      };
    });
  });

  // Load the iris data.
  d3.tsv('data.tsv', function (d) {
    d.sepalLength = +d.sepalLength;
    d.sepalWidth = +d.sepalWidth;
    d.petalLength = +d.petalLength;
    d.petalWidth = +d.petalWidth;
    return d;
  }, function(error, data) {

    // Set sizes once to initialize.
    setSizes();

    // Set sizes when the user resizes the browser.
    window.addEventListener('resize', setSizes);

    // Set the data.
    scatterPlot.data = data;
  });

  // Sets the `box` property on each visualization
  // to arrange them within the container div.
  function setSizes(){

    // Put the scatter plot on the left.
    scatterPlot.box = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      width: div.clientWidth / 2,
      height: div.clientHeight
    };

    // Put the bar chart on the right.
    barChart.box = {
      x: div.clientWidth / 2,
      y: 0,
      width: div.clientWidth / 2,
      height: div.clientHeight
    };
  }
}
main('sepalWidth','sepalLength');

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Currently, you are just creating an additional svg on top of the old one, when another axis is chosen by calling `main` again. You should implement a `model.when` for the axis change.

Comment: Also, I don't know if its the best to use an apparently unmaintained library, when starting with a project. The last commit in `model.js` is six years ago.